# How can I activate QoS in a LAN with 3 different routers?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, bandwidth

This may be easier than it looks, but I can't seem to make it work.

I have a LAN with 3 different routers.

Modem 1 is the ISPs main cable modem, Motorola SVG1202, in which the coax cable is connected and where all connection comes from. Its wireless radio is disabled (poor signal/range) and DHCP enabled. That's 192.168.0.1. It does not have QoS or bandwidth control capabilities AFAIK.

Router 2 is the second one, TP-LINK TL-WR941ND. It's a LAN to LAN connection and this one does have QoS and bandwidth control capabilities. That's 192.168.0.2.

Router 3 is the third one, a D-LINK DIR-610, connected to Router 2 on a LAN to LAN connection and with kinda odd QoS capabilities, but still, at least there's an option for that on the menus.

They all have the same SSID and password. Its the same network.

I tried setting up Bandwidth Control options on Router 2, but it didn't changed anything. I want all the IPs on the DHCP range (192.168.0.11 ~ 192.168.0.254) to be limited to a max of, lets say, 8Mb max. The IPs outside the DHCP range are used by my devices with static IPs, so they wont be limited and supposedly won't be affected by bufferbloat.
I did this exact configuration on Router 2 but it didn't changed anything: speedtest.net kept showing a download speed of 1.2MB/s on a device using a IP thats inside the DHCP range (bandwidth-controlled range). I don't want that.

I tried doing this config on Router 3, but it's kinda different and I didn't knew what to do. But I'll mess with that later.

I'm starting to wonder if this happened because the DHCP server is enabled on Modem 1 and he's the main guy on the connection. But it doesn't have QoS or bandwidth control capabilities, so I can't just "enable QoS" on it. Maybe if I switch the DHCP server to Router 2 (the one with bandwidth control options), but still, I don't know how do I manage the cables to do that... I think I need to plug it into WAN or something.

Please help me to decifrate what's happening here, guys.

Thanks.

Comment: For QoS to work correctly, it must be enabled with the same policies on all your network devices. Also, QoS is a broad term that spans everything from marking packets to taking action on the marked packets. Yous QoS markings and policies will not be honored on the public Internet. The best you can do is to shape or queue outbound traffic on the router from your LAN to the public Internet.

Comment: "The IPs outside the DHCP range are used by my devices with static IPs, so they wont be limited and supposedly won't be affected by bufferbloat." What makes you think they won't be affected by bufferbloat? Also, what's the goal behind this whole QoS exercise (What problems are you experiencing that you're trying to solve)? If the problem is things get laggy when there's congestion, then that's bufferbloat and you should solve it with Smart Queueing (e.g. FQ-CoDEL), not by using QoS to throttle certain kinds of flows or reprioritize traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the router you're applying QoS on isn't actually applying QoS to the traffic because it's not actually 'routing' said traffic.

If I understand your topology correctly, the routers are all daisy chained via their switchports (non-routed) and you have a single subnet spanning the three devices.

Keep in mind this suggestion could be totally wrong, but if your devices allow for this configuration, put DHCP on the QoSRouter and set it up like so:

```
|ISP|---|ModemDevice|---192.168.1.0/24---|QoSRouter|---192.168.0.0/24
```

The idea is that since your LAN traffic will be 'routed' out of the QoSRouter, it will 'know' to apply said QoS. (Also don't forget to set a static route / default gateway on QoSRouter pointing to ModemDevice).